How message from AWS DLQ gets deleted?
I am new to Queues so trying to understand this scenario
I have regular SQS Queue A and DLQ B and Lambda C.
Lambda C gets invoked by a message on SQS Queue.
Let say for whatever reason if something happens to Lambda C then message from SQS Queue A moves to DLQ B.
Then same Lambda C is invoked by message from DLQ B.
Let say if Lambda C is still not responding then what happens to message on DLQ B?
For how long that message will stay on DLQ B?
If Lambda C reads message from DLQ B then do i need to manually delete that message from DLQ B or it automatically gets deleted?

It probably does not make sense for your DLQ to trigger the same Lambda function that failed to process the original message. You need to understand why the failure happened.

A DLQ is just another SQS queue, with the same settings and behavior as any other SQS queue. SQS queues have a configurable message retention period of up to 14 days. The messages would eventually be deleted once they were in the DLQ past the configured retention period for your DLQ.

And what about if lambda gets invoked successfully but some process in lambda fails, in that case message will still be available on SQS or it will be deleted because it invoked lambda ?

Again, there is no difference here between the DLQ and any other SQS queue. If your Lambda function throws an error, the message is added back to the queue. If the message returns a success status, the message will be removed from the queue. If the message has been processed by Lambda for the number of times you have configured the Maximum Receives value on the queue, then the message will be deleted (just like any other queue).

makes sense thanks
